# changes impacted due to changing the version of poi from 2.5 to 3.5

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have been using the poi 2.5 final jar in one of my projects in which there is a program which is creating the excel sheet and now I have changed in my poi jar to poi 3.10 final version.

Now below piece of code which was working fine in my poi 2.5 version is not working in poi 3.5 please advise how can I correct this

```
short start = 0;
short end = 1;
excelSheet.addMergedRegion(new Region(0, start, 0, end));
excelSheetCell.setCellStyle(this.getCellStyle(recExcelReport, AREEesultsWriter.CellType.Summary_Total_Rows));
excelSheetCell = excelSheetRow.createCell((short) 1);

// Summary: Total Number of Rows
excelSheetRow = excelSheet.createRow(++rowCount);
excelSheetCell = excelSheetRow.createCell((short) 0);
excelSheetCell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
excelSheetCell.setCellValue("Total number of Rows");
excelSheetCell.setCellStyle(this.getCellStyle(recExcelReport, AREEesultsWriter.CellType.Summary_Total_Rows));
excelSheetCell = excelSheetRow.createCell((short) 1);
excelSheetCell.setCellStyle(this.getCellStyle(recExcelReport, AREEesultsWriter.CellType.Summary_Total_Rows));
excelSheetCell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
excelSheetCell.setCellFormula("SUM(B3:B6)");
```

Comment: Did you got any exception? Did you tried Debugging the code? If so please add the results, which will help in finding the issue asap.

Comment: Apache POI 2.5 is over 10 years old, 3.5 is still [6 years old with lots of bug fixes since then](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.5-final). Why are you not upgrading to the most recent one, and at the very least one from this decade?